# Network card three-pin connector

Tags: network-adapter, connector

I've got an Asus NX1101 gigabit network card.

It has a white connector with three pins. What is it for?

Comment: I get a "Runtime error" when I click that link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** The connector in question is definitely a [WOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) connector.

[image]

---

**Another edit:** The WOL cable is only [needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Intel.2FAMD_based_PC) on motherboards that do not support the [PME](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/netpm.mspx) portion of the PCI 2.2 standard.  If yours is a reasonably recent motherboard, then you should be able to configure WOL in the Power Management section of your BIOS and will not need the WOL cable.

---

If the connection looks like the following picture, then it is a [WOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) connection.

[image]

The WOL connection accepts a cable that looks something like the following picture.

[image]

Every WOL cable that I have ever seen has red and green wires, along with some other color.

The other end of the WOL cable connects to the WOL port on your motherboard.

If your motherboard has an integrated [NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller), then your motherboard may not have a WOL port.

Comment: Ok, but I can do WOL on this card without this cable. I guess this is a property of my BIOS?

Answer (score 4):

The link you have given goes to a graphics card.

If however it is what I think you are talking about on a network card - This usually goes to a special connector for the power unit to enable Magic Packets / Boot on Lan.

[image]

(see top corner)

However, if you are talking about the 3x2 adapter on the link you provided, that is a power adapter as the graphics card requires higher power than the socket can provide

[image]